# Zip excluding the BINARY files of my android application project

Tags: android, zip

I have been asked to create a zip file of my android application project and it is mentioned specifically 'do not zip BINARIES'.
What does that mean? Please let me know the procedure to do so.
Thank you.

Comment: The best to do is to ask them who asked you to do so.

Comment: Even they don't know. Else I wouldn't ask on SO

Comment: You should put in only the source like .java or .xml files and icons and so. Not compiled files produced by the ide. And not the final .apk. Just what you made yourself.